# Solr DataImportHandler ERROR DocBuilder Exception while processing

Tags: postgresql, solr, solr4, dih

I have been trying to get Solr DIH working with PostgreSQL for hours now and I cannot find the problem, as the Logger doesn't not tell me anthing helpful.
My aim is as simple as to synchronize the data from the database with Solr (using the DIH).

My setup is as follows:

Jetty, Windows 8

solrconfig.xml (nothing changed except for the following)

```
[...]
  <lib dir="../../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="../../../../dist/" regex="sqljdbc4.*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="../../../../dist/" regex="postgresql-.*\.jar" />
[...]
```

data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
              driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
              url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/solrdih" 
              user="solrdih" 
              password="solrdih"
              batchSize="100" />
  <document>
    <entity name="solrdih" 
            query="SELECT * FROM myTable">
       <field column="id" name="id" />
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

schema.xml (nothing changed except for the following)

```
[...]
   <fields>
      <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
      <field name="name" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
      <field name="description" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
[...]
```

Calling `http://localhost:8983/solr/solr/dataimport`, I get the following:

[image: Solr Logger]
It reads:

```
ERROR DocBuilder Exception while processing: solrdih document : SolrInputDocument[]:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT * FROM myTable Processing Document # 1
ERROR DataImporter Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to execute query: SELECT * FROM myTable Processing Document # 1
```

[image: XML response browser]

Could someone please provide hints where to look for the error?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In which container is your Solr running? A Tomcat or is it running with the bundled Jetty? And are you running it on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Thank you for the question @cheffe I added the information above. It's Windows and Jetty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this error came from all the way down in Postgres and everything works fine since I made changes to pg_hba.conf

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

to

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```